# Android Bitmap to bytearray differs based on device

Tags: android, kotlin, hash

I am trying to calculate a hash value for an image, so that when the user renames the file, the app can still recognize it.

So for now I've experimented using hash values and I thought I will calculate a SHA-256 of the image. Of course, before deployment I wanted to test this app, so I've created an instrumentation test.

The issue is, that it works locally, but when I run it on Github Actions (using `reactivecircus/android-emulator-runner@v2`), the tests fail. I did not pay much attention to the differences between the 2 devices, they are different in API versions (26 and 31) and maybe even architecture.

Here is the code that runs differently:

```kotlin
    val expected = "bcc060400f0da1b937307daafecc12b5016334cd5023aafa47ff5c31b9a1f2ca"

    val bitmap =
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            context.resources,
            R.drawable.unsplash_flowers,
        )

    val byteArray =
        bitmap.run {
            val size: Int = this.rowBytes * this.height
            val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size)
            this.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer)
            return@run byteBuffer.array()
        }
    val sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
    val digest = sha256.digest(byteArray)
    val actual = BigInteger(1, digest).toString(16)

    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual)

    bitmap.recycle()
```

And then later I've also created a test to calculate the pure hash value (to make sure the hash algorithm works as expected.

So this code runs equally (tests pass in both cases):

```kotlin
    val expected = "da9a9fc7b09edde9cc23cec9b7e11a71fb0ab4d2ddd8af8af905306f3e1456fb"
    val sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
    val digest = sha256.digest("sdsdsds".toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
    val actual = BigInteger(1, digest).toString(16)

    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual)
```

so this leaves me with the first part of the code `Bitmap` conversion code that can be different:

```kotlin
    val bitmap =
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            context.resources,
            R.drawable.unsplash_flowers,
        )

    val byteArray =
        bitmap.run {
            val size: Int = this.rowBytes * this.height
            val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size)
            this.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer)
            return@run byteBuffer.array()
        }
```

The 2 functions that can be different are

- `BitmapFactory.decodeResource`
- `copyPixelsToBuffer`

Can these functions be different in different Android versions?

Actually, the only thing I care about is that this hash does not change between Android versions, it can be different on different devices.

Comment: Start with the beginning please. What is `R.drawable.unsplash_flowers` ? And is the file behind it the same? A jpg? A png? And how could a user ever rename that file?

Comment: `R.drawable.unsplash_flowers` is a `.jpg` file, that is inside the `res/drawable` folder. There is no other file named like that in the project, so I assume it must be the same.

Comment: Why are you afraid the user renames it? Which is impossible.

Comment: Jpeg is lossy so creating a bitmap using decode from resource can easily give different results on different android versions. I wonder why you would make a bitmap first. Better do the calculation for the bytes of the file.

Comment: I am creating a test for calculating the hash. The production app will use this same hash calculation algorithm on arbitrary images in other folders. The user may have access to these folders.

Comment: Calculate the hash for the bytes of the file. Dont use an intermediate bitmap. If you take the file itself you can hash any kind of file.

Comment: Okay, I'll test this out.

Comment: You were right @blackapps . It happened because the file was `.jpg`.  The above algorithm works with `.png` files and of course raw file bytearray as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you can write it as an answer if you want to.